# Regex for date of birth with maximum age

Tags: python, regex, date, match

I am looking for a regular expression in Python which mathes for date of birth is the given format: `dd.mm.YYYY`

For example:

- 31.12.1999 (31st of December)
- 02.07.2021

I have provided more examples in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5pb72F/1).

Dates which are older as 01.01.1920 should not match!!!

Comment: If you know the format, why you do not convert to integer and check the tree components? It will be much fast and less resource, for sure

Comment: Just a suggestion -- use a regex to restrict the *format*, but use comparisons to restrict the *ranges*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ned a regex for my task. I am building a bot. The bot validates multiple inputs like birthday, city, name, zip code,...The bot only expects a regex as validation rule. If this is not possible or very difficult to do, I have to redesign the bot quite a lot

Comment: Regex is not designed to do less/greater comparisons.  If that's the only tool you have to work with, you're out of luck.  Good luck with your redesign.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's super cursed but it can technically be done...

Comment: @orlp I look forward to your answer then.

Comment: This cannot be done perfectly, and not because the constraint about 01.01.1920, because it's possible to check for number ranges in a regex. The problem is that It would require an extremely complex regex to find these invalid dates invalid: 31.06.2021 (June only has 30 days), 29.02.2021 (2021 is not a leap year).

Comment: @kol 'Extremely complex' does not mean impossible. Modular structures (and leap days are predictable modulo 400).

Comment: @orlp OK, not impossible, but so long that it would be practically unusable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. I dind't know that it would be so complex. Maybe I should consider to redesign the bot then creating a super complex regex...

Comment: @MarkRansom There you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?:[0-2][1-9]|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[12])\.(?:19[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d{3})$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBDdYA/1/)

Be aware that this will not catch dates like 31.02.2021, that is, it is not sophisticated enough to know how many days are in any given month and it is hopeless to try to come up with a regex that can do that because February is problematic because the regex can't compute which years are leap years.

This will also allow future dates such as 01.01.3099 (you do want this to be work for the future, no?).

**Update**

You really need to be using the `datetime` class from the `datetime` package and, if you want to insist that the date and month fields contain two digits, a regex just to ensure the format:

```python
import re
from datetime import datetime, date

validated = False # assume not validated
s = '31.03.2019'
m = re.fullmatch(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}', s)
if m:
    # we have ensured the correct number of digits:
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m.%Y').date()
        if d >= date(1920, 1, 1):
            validated = True
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(validated)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, days in the future are an other problem which I did't thought about. Maybe I was to optimistic to handle the problem with a regular expression

Comment: This looks like the most practical solution!

Answer (score 2):

As I said, it can be done with a very convoluted regex. However, I do not actually recommend using this, I just had fun writing it as a challenge. You should in reality use a very permissive regex and validate the ranges in code.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsjMZb/1).

```
# Easy dates, those <= 28th, valid for all months/years.
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19[2-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9])    

|

# Validate the 29th of Februari for 1920-1999.
29\.02\.19([3579][26]|[2468][048])

|

# Validate the 29th of Februari for 2000-2999.
29\.02\.((2[0-9])(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|2000|2400|2800)

|

# Validate 29th and 30th.
(29|30)\.(01|0[3-9]|1[0-2])\.(19[2-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9])

|

# Validate 31st.
31\.(01|03|05|07|08|10|12)\.(19[2-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

Comment: Wow, this is indeed a very complex regex. I will mark it as a solution but probably try to redesigin my bots logic. The most practical solution is the one mention from @Booboo

Comment: Has your regex taken into account *all* the rules that govern which years are leap years?

Comment: @Booboo As far as I'm aware (leap year if divisible by 4, unless divisible by 100, except yes again if divisible by 400), yes. My regex only accepts dates in the years 1920-2999 and I believe it is correct for all of those dates (barring any future calendar changes).

Answer (score -1):

`\d\{2}.\d\{2}.\d{4}`

Validating the value of the dates should be done at the application level.